# The shortcut keys for switching keyboard layout randomly stop working

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switches between Hebrew/English keyboard layouts.

Every few hours, this stops working. The layout-switching icon in the panel continues to work.

If I go back to Settings->Keyboard, and again configure the keyboard shortcut, it starts working again. The same thing happens if I choose <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>or some other key for layout-switching.

How can prevent this problem?